# Get amount of rows in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm using a prepared statement query which is builded with a string concatenation:

- `$sqlitemsparse`- the "Select" clause
- `$sqlitemsparse .` - the "Where" clause
- `$sqlitemsparse2` - the "Limit" selection

This is working as expected.

Now, additionally, I need the amount of result rows from the `$sqlitemsparse` and `$sqlitemsparse .` query (without the "LIMIT" selection).

I've tried it with the mysqli_num_rows function in combination with a new mysqli_query but I get the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in...
```

**Code:**

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

// Variable to bind
$classid = "4";

$sqlitemsparse = "SELECT * FROM itemSparse INNER JOIN item ON item.id = itemSparse.id";

$sqlitemsparse.= " WHERE item.ClassID = ?";

$sqlitemsparse2 = " LIMIT 0, 10";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sqlitemsparse . $sqlitemsparse2)) {
    echo "SQL Failed";
} else {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $classid);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $resultitemsparse = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

    while($rowitemsparse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultitemsparse)) {
        $rowsitemsparse[] = $rowitemsparse;
    }
}

$number_filter_row = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlitemsparse));
```

Comment: First of all, enable error reporting for mysqli [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: I enabled the error reporting and the output is the "Warning" message. My idea was to repeat the `sqlitemsparse` query so I can count the rows without the `$sqlitemsparse2` limit query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the count of the rows matched by the same prepared statement but without the `LIMIT` then you need to execute another prepared statement, but this time with `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT *`.

```
<?php

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");

// Variable to bind
$classid = "4";

$sqlitemsparse = "SELECT * FROM itemSparse INNER JOIN item ON item.id = itemSparse.id";
$sqlitemsparse .= " WHERE item.ClassID = ?";

$sqlitemsparse2 = " LIMIT 0, 10";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlitemsparse . $sqlitemsparse2);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $classid);
$stmt->execute();
$resultitemsparse = $stmt->get_result();
$rowsitemsparse = $resultitemsparse->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$sqlitemsparse = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM itemSparse INNER JOIN item ON item.id = itemSparse.id";
$sqlitemsparse .= " WHERE item.ClassID = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlitemsparse);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $classid);
$stmt->execute();
$resultitemsparse = $stmt->get_result();
$row_count = $resultitemsparse->fetch_row()[0]; // first column of first row
```

Comment: So there is no other possibility than modifying the `$sqlitemsparse` query with `SELECT COUNT(*)`? My initial idea was to use the exact same `$sqlitemsparse` two times.

Comment: @Berstos No. The other way would be to fetch everything from database into PHP and let PHP do all the work, but that would defeat the purpose of having a database. SQL can efficiently perform a count so this is really not a problem.